# Pie Chart Label Lines with key and y value and Legend position on right side with angular-nvd3

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I need to print the label with both key and value and also with the label line.and legends should display on the right side of the pie chart.What are the changes I have to do in js files?

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3 Donut Chart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.5/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

  </body>

</html>
```

// this is the code i am using in my controller
   var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 450,
                x: function(d){return d.key;},
                y: function(d){return d.y;},
                showLabels: true,
                labelsOutside: true,
                legend: {
                    margin: {
                        top: 5,
                        right: 70,
                        bottom: 5,
                        left: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        };
 $scope.xFunction = function() {
        return function(d) {
            return d.key
        }
        //.legendPosition("right");
    };
    $scope.yFunction = function() {
        return function(d) {
            return d.y
        }
        //.legendPosition("right");
    };
        $scope.data = [
            {
                key: "One",
                y: 5
            },
            {
                key: "Two",
                y: 2
            },
            {
                key: "Three",
                y: 9
            },
            {
                key: "Four",
                y: 7
            },
            {
                key: "Five",
                y: 4
            },
            {
                key: "Six",
                y: 3
            },
            {
                key: "Seven",
                y: .5
            }
        ];
});
```

Please, anyone, help me...I am looking for the solution. you can run this code in plunker editor.